# Use Google Maps API to get City from Zip code and then write it to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps

I have a JSON file with a bunch of different zip codes. What I want to do is leverage the Google Maps API to retrieve the City associated with a zip code, and then write it to the JSON file.

So far I have a script which is correctly grabbing the city from the results. How would I go about writing these cities to the JSON file?

**Here's my JSON data:**

```
[
  {
    "State": "Oklahoma",
    "ZIP": 73169
  },
  {
    "State": "Oklahoma",
    "ZIP": 73169
  },
  {
    "State": "Oklahoma",
    "ZIP": 73170
  },
  {
    "State": "Oklahoma",
    "ZIP": 73172
  },
  {
    "State": "Oklahoma",
    "ZIP": 73173
  }
]
```

**And here's my script:**

```
$(function() {
  $.get('locations.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      var zip = item.ZIP;
      var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zip + "&key=AIzaSyD_YqB4d_-xKcmNP9jJCiPkJYDS8J3f6pI";
      $.get(url, function(loc) {
          for(var i=0;i<loc.results.length;i++) {
            var address = loc.results[i].formatted_address;
            var city = address.split(',', 1)[0]
            console.log(city);
          }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[Here's a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0j6Q00XJbfWkGNslroD9?p=preview)

**UPDATE:**

I found a way to write to my JSON file using NodeJS [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508834/how-to-write-a-script-to-edit-a-json-file), the code below successfully updates the "City" to "test" for each of my JSON objects, now I guess I just need help on incorporating this into my jQuery code:

```
fs = require('fs');
var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('locations.json').toString());
m.forEach(function(p){
    p.City = "test";
});
fs.writeFile('locations.json', JSON.stringify(m));
```

I would also be willing to use PHP if that would be easier.

## **Yet another attempt(closest to what I'm trying to do):**

The plan is to only use this script once to populate the JSON with all of the cities. So I figured I would try to do it client-side where I can just log out some JSON data and then copy/paste it manually rather than relying on server-side code to do it for me. That brought me to this solution:

```js
$(function() {
   var item = [];
   var locations = [
     {
       "State": "Oklahoma",
       "ZIP": "73169",
       "City": ""
     },
     {
       "State": "Oklahoma",
       "ZIP": "73169",
       "City": ""
     },
     {
       "State": "Oklahoma",
       "ZIP": "73170",
       "City": ""
     },
     {
       "State": "Oklahoma",
       "ZIP": "73172",
       "City": ""
     },
     {
       "State": "Oklahoma",
       "ZIP": "73173",
       "City": ""
     }
   ];

      $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
    var zip = item.ZIP;
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zip + "&key=AIzaSyA75wif8_yewifGSqVFnR3U50zuW_EnAns";
    $.get(url, function(loc) {
     for(var i=0;i<loc.results.length;i++) {
      var address = loc.results[i].formatted_address;
      var city = address.split(',', 1)[0];
      item.City = city;
      console.log(item);
     }
    });
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I log out `item` within the `for` statement, it returns everything correctly. How could I output this as a single array in JSON format?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Are you trying to create and save a file in client side JavaScript (ie. running in the browser)?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how or where the file is saved, I will just be running this one time to populate the cities into the JSON file and then never using it again. Even if I could just modify the JSON on the client-side with the ability to copy/paste it into the JSON file that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write a file from browser directly. You could create a blob or a data URL and provide a link from where the file could be downloaded like [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800715/3349511).

Or, since you have Node.js, maybe just run a script in the shell. This example requires `npm install request request-promise-native`, but you could use Node.js [https API](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) instead. Also, no error handling in the example.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

const baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=<your key>&address=';
const locations = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('locations.json', 'utf8'));

Promise.all(locations.map((location) => {
  return request
    .get(baseUrl + location.ZIP)
    .then((result) => {
      location.city = JSON.parse(result).results[0].formatted_address.split(',', 1)[0];
      return location;
    });
})).then((results) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('results.json', JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

**Edit:** I just read your comment about even copy-paste being sufficient for you. You can use the approach above also in browser, no need for jQuery:

```
Promise.all(locations.map((location) => {
  return fetch(baseUrl + location.ZIP)
    .then((result) => {
      location.city = result.results[0].formatted_address.split(',', 1)[0];
      return location;
    });
})).then((results) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```